# Product of each element in column A raised to the power of column B in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two rows, one with the probability of some event occurring, the other with the number of times that particular event occurred.  below is a sample:

```
0.879088785 0.029205607 0.061331776 0.029205607 0.000292056 0.000292056 0.000292056 0.000292056
 6  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

What I am looking for is to get the PRODUCT of each element in column A raised to the corresponding POWER in column B.  So for my example:

```
0.879088785^6 * 0.029205607^0 * 0.061331776^0 * 0.029205607^0 * 0.000292056^0 * 0.000292056^0 * 0.000292056^1 * 0.000292056^0
= 0.00013479151983607446
```

Does anyone know a quick way to do this? I was hoping for a function like SUMPRODUCT() which would just take each row as inputs, but it seems no PRODUCTPOWER() function exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use PRODUCT as an array formula

```
=PRODUCT(A4:A11^B4:B11)
```

This needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula:

[image]

---

If one does not like the `^` they can use POWER instead:

```
=PRODUCT(POWER(A4:A11,B4:B11))
```

Still an array formula.

Comment: That will be incredibly useful.  Thank you!